# Suppress capturing progress bar updates into the log file [R]

Tags: r, logging, r-package

I have a several functions performing some parallel looped operations on my input data (I use doParallel and foreach packages to do so). Within those functions I included progress bar using utils::txtProgressBar() to control the execution.

I decided to wrap those functions into the R package and to write a wrapper function which would allow to run an entire pipeline at once [explained below]. Inside this wrapper, I want to have a code section which would produce a log file. Below I paste the pseudo code which I hope would present the main idea.

Unfortunately with this approach, produced test log files are very large, because progress bars are captured and stored each time they refresh. I would like to save into the log file only the error message (if it would be thrown for some reason - my functions have assertions written with assertthat & checkmate) and the final message from each stage (produced by cat(); it is a statement which looks like this "XXX stage completed".

Below I am pasting some pseudo code with the main idea of the wrapper and the progress bars.

```
wrapper_function <- function(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, save_dir){
  
  # console message
  cat('Welcome to PKG_name', as.character(utils::packageVersion("PKG_name")), '\n',
      'Pipeline initialized:', as.character(Sys.time()),'\n','\n')
  
  # Create a log file
    if (dir.exists(file.path(save_dir))) {
        log_filename <- paste(format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"), "_PKG_name.log", sep = "")
        log_filepath <- file.path(save_dir, log_filename, fsep = .Platform$file.sep)
        log_file <- file(log_file_path, open = "a")
        sink(log_file, append=TRUE, split = TRUE, type='output')
        on.exit(sink(file=NULL, type = 'output'))
    }

  example_output <- example_looped_function(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
  example_output2 <- example_looped_function(example_output)
  example_output3 <- example_looped_function(example_output2, arg1, arg2)
  pipeline_output <- function_4(example_output2)

  cat('Processing finished.')
  cat('Thank you for using PKG_name')
  
  log_file <- file(log_filepath, open = "a")
  sink(log_file, append=TRUE, split = TRUE, type='output')
  
  
  return(pipeline_output)
}



#Example of progress bar in functions:

pb <- utils::txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(index_list), style = 3, width = 50, char = "=")

  for (indx in 1:length(index_list)){
    example_loop <- foreach::foreach(something) %dopar% some_function(something, something_else)
    utils::setTxtProgressBar(pb, indx)
  }
  close(pb)
```

I would be grateful for help in removing progress bar from the log files.

[explanation] there are some reasons why I would like to have both options included: to run the entire pipeline at once by launching wrapper function or to perform only a certain step of the analysis using particular function.

Comment: `utils::txtProgressBar()` outputs to standard output (stdout) by default. This is an unfortunate, and unusual design choice. Instead, you want progress updates to be outputted to standard error (stderr).  You can achieve this by passing `utils::txtProgressBar(... file = stderr())`.  See <https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/Wishlist-for-R/issues/75> for more details

Comment: (Disclaimer: I'm the author).  I recommend using `doFuture::registerDoFuture()` with `future::plan("multisession", workers = num_cores)` instead of `doParallel::registerDoParallel(...)`.  It will give you _proper_ handling of standard output, messages, and warnings.  With this, you can then use the **progressr** package to get near-live progress updates. See <https://progressr.futureverse.org/#foreach-with-dofuture> for an example.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I did not know those packages well, so I stuck to things I was familiar with. However, I will use this in the next release. Now I am ahead of the preprint, so I do not have time to rewrite the code.

Comment: Got it. Though, I highly recommend that you change to use `utils::txtProgressBar(... file = stderr())`.  If not, those progress bars will end up in people's Rmarkdown reports, if they use your functions in those.

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted, according to your suggestion. TBH, I did not even think about running this pipeline in Rmarkdown report - that would not be the best idea. The package is intended to process very large & weirdly formatted datasets and the outcome of the core pipeline (output dataframe) is intended to be used in the reports (loaded with vroom or fread for instance). I even put that disclaimer in manual. And as I said, I will try to switch to the packages recommended by you, but first I have to get familiar with them, which would require time. But, once again, kudos to you.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may encounter similar problem in R - here is a solution I found:

1. I rewrote the wrapper_function: instead of calling numerous functions one by one I just put the code executed by them directly
2. I used redirected loop outputs to NULL file using sink.

Below is a pseudocode with the rationale:

```
wrapper_function <- function(some arguments, save_dir){
  
  # console message
  cat('Welcome to PKG_name', as.character(utils::packageVersion("PKG_name")), '\n',
      'Pipeline initialized:', as.character(Sys.time()),'\n','\n')
  
  # Create a log file
    if (dir.exists(file.path(save_dir))) {
        log_filename <- paste(format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"), "_PKG_name.log", sep = "")
        log_filepath <- file.path(save_dir, log_filename, fsep = .Platform$file.sep)
        log_file <- file(log_file_path, open = "a")
        sink(log_file, append=TRUE, split = TRUE, type='output')
        on.exit(sink(file=NULL, type = 'output'))
    }
    
  # start cluster
  doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = num_cores)

  ################################################### 
  # function with loop
  ################################################### 
  # header for progress bar
  cat(paste('Doing something something...', '\n', sep=''))
  
  #SINK #1 <- THIS DOES THE TRICK
  sink(file=NULL, type = 'output')
  close(log_file)

  # progress bar
  pb <- utils::txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = 10, style = 3, width = 50, char = "=")

  # loop 
  for (x in 1:10){

    #do something in parallel using %dopar%

  }

  close(pb)
  
  #SINK #2 <- THIS DOES THE TRICK
  log_file <- file(log_filepath, open = "a")
  sink(log_file, append=TRUE, split = TRUE, type='output')

  # after all of the functions with parallel computing
  doParallel::stopImplicitCluster()
  

  cat('Processing finished.')
  cat('Thank you for using PKG_name')
  
  log_file <- file(log_filepath, open = "a")
  sink(log_file, append=TRUE, split = TRUE, type='output')
  
  
  return(pipeline_output)

}
```

And the log file records the steps captured from cat() function without capturing the progress bar updates.

May not be the neatest and prettiest, but this works.